# Algunos iconos de la página Font Awesome no se ven

Tags: html, css, web, font-awesome

estoy haciendo una página y estoy usando varios iconos de esa web, algunos se ven y otros no. ¿Alguien sabe que pasa?

Importo todos los iconos de la version 6.0.0 con esta línea:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-9usAa10IRO0HhonpyAIVpjrylPvoDwiPUiKdWk5t3PyolY1cOd4DSE0Ga+ri4AuTroPR5aQvXU9xC6qOPnzFeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

Comment: ¿Qué iconos estás tratando de importar? ¿Ya verificaste que solo estés tratando de usar iconos de la versión gratuita?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que todo, debes colocar la etiqueta **link** dentro de la etiqueta **head**

Y por otra parte te recomiendo que utilices Font Awesome en su versión 4.7.0

Aquí te dejo el ejemplo práctico:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Página Web</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="fa fa-info-circle"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-edit"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-eye"></span>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

buenas.

Por lo general cuando no aparecen los iconos se debe o bien a una mala implementación o bien estás usando iconos que no se encuentran dentro de la versión gratuita.

Te aconsejo a la hora de buscar iconos selecciones está opción para asegurarte que puedas usarlos.

[image: Captura de fontawesome]